# mySQL cross-db/table update is blowing my mind

Tags: mysql

Database `A` contains table `X`

Database `B` contains tables `Y and Z`

`A.X` contains fields `order_number` and `dude`

`B.Y` contains fields `order`, `dude_number`
`B.Z` contains fields `other_dude_number` and `dude_type`

I want `A.X.dude` to update to `B.Y.dude_number` based on: `(B.Y.order = A.X.order_number) AND ((B.Z.other_dude_number = B.Y.dude_number) AND (B.Z.dude_type = 6))`

I've been pumping out mySQL queries for two hours to try and get this to work. I'm almost sure I need a **UNION** in there, somewhere, but I'm not familiar enough with **UNION** to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE A.X
  JOIN B.Y ON Y.`order` = X.order_number
  JOIN B.Z ON Z.other_dude_number = Y.dude_number
SET      X.dude = Y.dude_number
WHERE    Z.dude_type = 6
```

Comment: You need to `JOIN B.Z` as well.

Comment: @ypercube: Ooops.  Corrected.  :)

Comment: SET A.X.dude = B.Y.dude_number

Comment: @Nathan: Crikey!  Less haste, methinks.  Thank you.

Comment: Excelsior! I love this site!

Comment: @ypercube: Are db qualifiers not valid in column references?  And I thought that one need not quote reserved words if they are table-qualified, since they won't be tokenised?

Comment: @ypercube: Indeed, see [Identifier Qualifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) "*In MySQL, you can refer to a table column using any of the following forms ... `db_name.tbl_name.col_name`*" and [Reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html) "*Exception: A word that follows a period in a qualified name must be an identifier, so it need not be quoted even if it is reserved*".